# <Debugging> How to edit new items & how to not check for the first row item?

Tags: javascript, html

How to edit new items & how to not check for the first row item?
I want to keep using the 'onAdd and Create Item' functions.
but when I click other new rows(new items' names), the 'checkbox' event is applied to the very first row too.
**1) How to NOT checking the first row?**

Since I wrote the code by using 'innterHTML' when creating Items, I think this is why I can not edit the new items.
**2) How to Link 'Edit' function to new items?**

```js
const items = document.querySelector('.items');
const input = document.querySelector('.footer_input');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.footer_button');
const form = document.querySelector('.new_form');
const itemName = document.querySelector('.item_name');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  onAdd();
});

function onAdd() {
  const text = input.value;
  if (text === '') {
    input.focus();
    return;
  }
  const item = createItem(text);
  items.appendChild(item);
  item.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center' });
  input.value = '';
  input.focus();
}

let id = 0; // UUID
function createItem(text) {
  const itemRow = document.createElement('li');
  itemRow.setAttribute('class', 'item_row');
  itemRow.setAttribute('data-id', id);
  itemRow.innerHTML = `
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="item_name_check" value="1"/>
      <label for="item_name_check" class="item_name">${text}</label>
      <div class="button_container">
            <button class="item_edit" >Edit</button>
            <button class="item_delete" >
                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" data-id=${id}></i>
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item_divider"></div>`;
  id++;
  return itemRow;
}

items.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const id = event.target.dataset.id;
  if (id) {
    const toBeDeleted = document.querySelector(`.item_row[data-id="${id}"]`);
    toBeDeleted.remove();
  }
});


const editBTN = document.querySelector('.item_edit');
const newItemInput = document.createElement('input');
editBTN.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.innerText === 'Update') {
    itemName.innerText = newItemInput.value;
    newItemInput.value = '';
    editBTN.innerText = 'Edit';
  } else {
    itemName.innerHTML = '';

    newItemInput.type = 'text';
    newItemInput.className = 'newItemInput';
    itemName.appendChild(newItemInput);
    newItemInput.focus();

    editBTN.innerText = 'Update';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>TodoList</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dde5490d2b.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9eb162ac0d.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="list">
      <header class="header">Shopping List</header>
      <ul class="items">
        <li class="item_row">
          <div class="item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="item_name_check" value="1"/>
            <label for="item_name_check" class="item_name">Egg</label>
            <div class="button_container">
              <button class="item_edit">Edit</button>
              <button class="item_delete">
                <i class="fas fa-trash-can"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            
          </div>
          <div class="item_divider"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="new_form">
        <footer class="footer">
          <input type="text" class="footer_input" />
          <button type="submit" class="footer_button">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
        </footer>
      </form>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `id` is not a UUID

Comment: but i made id++.. is it a reason why i have bugs?